# SourceTreeのインストールにログインは必要？

Tags: sourcetree

下記URLで、Windows向けダウンロードより、exeファイルを入手できてダブルクリックを押したのですがBitbucketにログインしないと先に進めないような形になってしまっています。

SourceTreeのインストールの仕方のサイトを見ても、Bitbucketにログインするような画面がないように思うのですが、Bitbucketのアカウントを作ってログインできる状態にならなければSourceTreeのインストールはできないのでしょうか。

https://ja.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree

Comment: これ、記憶ベースで話すと、去年あたりのリリースで変わっていて、古い文献だと、アカウントの件って出てないんですよね。こちらのプロジェクトでも課題になりました。

Comment: 確かに[この回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46629927/5989200)によると 2015 年リリースの SourceTree v1.6 時点ではログイン不要だったようです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

はい、2018年12月現在 SourceTree はインストール時に Atlassian アカウントでのログインが必要です。GitHub 等の他サービスとの紐付けはその後行うことになります。

参考

- [Can sourcetree be used without atlassian account, e.g. for github?](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Can-sourcetree-be-used-without-atlassian-account-e-g-for-github/qaq-p/782362)
- [Install SourceTree without an Atlassian account?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41385705/5989200)